# ag-grid: setFilterModel() unable to apply filter to async/callback set filter

Tags: ag-grid

ag-grid's asynchronous set filters. These provide significant speed increases and lower transmission payloads for our clients, a very valuable feature. However, we also invoke .setFilterModel in onGridReady to load cached and saved filter configurations. These two features are unable to operate in tandem.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE Method:

Open https://embed.plnkr.co/hhgPgNM2plVpIQbB5aGj/ 
Select Filter icon on Set filter col column Wait for Set Filter to populate Click Apply Filter using setFilterModel() button. 
Observe (function behaves as expected)

How Can setFilterModel() initiates values callback function, on success filter model is applied ? or please suggest how can I use synchronous callbacks instead of asynch issue.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I played around with the plunker and modified the applyFilter() slightly and this works.
Basically you need to notify ag-grid that you have applied the filter -

```
function applyFilter(){
// get instance of set filter
var valueFilterComponent = gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance('value');  

// use api to select value
valueFilterComponent.selectValue('value 1');

// let ag-grid know that filter was applied
valueFilterComponent.onFilterChanged();
}
```

More on set filters [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/#set-filter-model)

Comment: Thanks.. But will not work if we have more than one column in grid table and multiple values to set for valuefilter

Comment: you can use selectValues api function to select multiple values. And this is just an example using one column which was asked in the original question